# Why TS is unsafe in unary arithmetic operations but not in binary ones?

Tags: typescript, math, compiler-construction

**In arithmetics** the following is true: let '*a*' be any positive real number, so:

```
-a = a*(-1)
```

Typescript compiler seems to not reproduce arithmetic rules in a type-safe way. Look:

**(I) Work as expected**

Following lines produces this error message: *"the left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'big-int', or enum type"*

```js
const f = (a: string) => a*(-1)  // error
const g = (a: {}) => a*(-1)      // error
```

**(II) Do not work as expected**

In below scenario all arithmetic computation are unsafely perfomed with non-numerical types and no compile-time error is raised.

```js
const f = (a: string) => -a
const g = (a: {}) => -a 

console.log(f('hi there')) // produces 'NaN' !
console.log(g('hi there')) // produces 'NaN'

console.log(g(2)) // produces -2
```

---

**QUESTION**

- Why TS is not as safe in the unary operator as it is in the binary operator?

NOTES: *TS version 3.7.2* / Type 'unknown' works as expected

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears you're only trying to find out if you should make a bug report for TypeScript and not really asking a question about any specific programming problem. Questions like that are better asked in the context of their communities like filing a bug report and waiting on an appropriate response there (or searching for it there yourself to see if one is already open).

Comment: I reframed my question. Hope you downgrade your off-topic voting bacause it is fairly objective. TS is a static language constructed over a dynamic language. No other production-level static language like C++, Haskall, Java, Delphi, etc have this design. This impose to the language a serie of edge cases that are considered perferctly normal. I would like others to explain this special case to me. Thank you for your feed back.

Comment: The unary operator basically tries to convert the operand into a number: in this case, `-a` is totally valid on any string or object. We would be in so much trouble with use of unary operator on a string throws an error for example. It's widely used as a near-substitute for `parseInt()`

Comment: @Terry, the binary operator also converts the operands into numbers. What is the reason TS compiler is preventing me to avoid type-mismatch in binary operator. but is not performing the same prevention in unary operator ? Is there any reason to that correspondent asymmetry ? Thank you.

Comment: Just because they're arithmetically equivalent does not mean they are the same in JavaScript. Basically, `a*(-1)` is an arithmetic operation involving two operands and requires both to be a number and does not perform any implicit conversion. `-a` on the other hand, performs conversion and therefore can accept any type, because the unary operator actually internally calls `valueOf()` or `toString()` if the operand is not of type `number`.

Comment: @Terry you bring a right definition about how Javascript works and I agree 100% with your definition. But the reason to use Typescript is just to protect the programer against this kind of type mismatch. There is a reasonable reason for TS giving up to perform its safety work in the particular case of unary operation? In other words: Why TS cannot be as safe in the unary operator as it is in the binary operator?

Comment: @Terry Binary operators also perform type conversion

Comment: I've created an ESLint plugin to catch this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-unary-minus

Answer (score 7):

The ECMAScript specification states that the [unary `+`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-unary-plus-operator) and [unary `-`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-unary-minus-operator) operators both perform the abstract operation [`ToNumber()`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-tonumber) on their input expression:

> [12.5.6 Unary + Operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-unary-plus-operator)
>
> > NOTE The unary + operator **converts its operand to Number type***.
>
> [12.5.6.1 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-unary-plus-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation)
>
> [UnaryExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-UnaryExpression) : + [UnaryExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-UnaryExpression)
>
> 1. Let expr be the result of evaluating [UnaryExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-UnaryExpression).
> 2. Return ? [ToNumber](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-tonumber)(? [GetValue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-getvalue)(expr)).
>
> [12.5.7 Unary - Operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-unary-minus-operator)
>
> > NOTE The unary - operator **converts its operand to Number type*** and then negates it. Negating +0 produces -0, and negating -0 produces +0.
>
> [12.5.7.1 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-unary-plus-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation)
>
> [UnaryExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-UnaryExpression) : - [UnaryExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-UnaryExpression)
>
> 1. Let expr be the result of evaluating [UnaryExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-UnaryExpression).
> 2. Let oldValue be ? [ToNumber](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-tonumber)(? [GetValue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-getvalue)(expr)).
> 3. If oldValue is NaN, return NaN.
> 4. Return the result of negating oldValue; that is, compute a Number with the same magnitude but opposite sign.
>
> *<sub>emphasis added</sub>

TypeScript has no reason to impose arbitrary restrictions on the accepted types, since the primary intended usage, according to the specification, is to **perform type conversion**.

---

To address [Emanuel Vintilă](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3502980)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59573311#comment105332781_59573311) on the question above:

> Binary operators also perform type conversion

The specification does not use the same language, i.e.

> [...] converts its operand to Number type

under [MultiplicativeExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-multiplicative-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation); that is, while the multiplicative `*`, `/`, `%` operators *do* perform type conversion, it is *not* the primary intended usage for them.

Comment: There is no reason to believe that the note on spec is implying 'intentional semantic for the operator' other than to **explain internal details**.
The notes are motivated by these two particular caracteristics of unary operators:  A) _unary +_ is sometimes tricky because `+'1'` still results into one, which can confuse for external observer making it look like nothing happened but a type conversion happned. B) _unary -_ the intention of note is to highlight the edge case that `-'0'` does not results in `0` as normally expected but `-0`. By the way thank you for your answer.

Comment: @FlavioVilante RE `the intention of note is to highlight the edge case that...` I would be inclined to agree with you, except that no such note exists to point out the implicit conversion behavior of multiplicative operators. The absence of the note there implies that the specification goes out of its way to state the primary purpose of the unary operators in the bolded part of each respective note, whereas the primary purpose of multiplicative operators is understood to be self-evident, and implicit conversion is just a side-effect of keeping the language semantics consistent.

Comment: IMHO, the choice of type safety in TypeScript comes down to a matter of de-facto convention. Since it's generally agreed that the unary plus operator's sole purpose (as evidenced by the very simple algorithm in 12.5.6.1) is to perform type conversion. So we can at least agree that `+"foo"` clearly states the intention to cast a string to a number. If we allow `any` for unary `+`, but not for unary `-`, we end up with the scenario where people will have to work _around_ the compiler by using `-+"foo"` instead of the more conventional, less noisy, and less redundant `-"foo"` </rant>

Comment: I think we got to the conclusion: The reason of this behavior is that JS has this de-facto convention (slightly documented in the spec) and TS as a superset of JS is trying to conform to it. Even though this kind of behavior obfuscate code legibility.Thank you a lot for your colaboration.